# SQL Server Not Recognizing Text in varchar

Tags: sql-server, excel

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.  I have a spreadsheet that I'm manually importing into an existing table in an AZURE database using the SQL Server Import and Export Studio.

The column I'm hitting the issue with is a varchar(55).  It's coming from a spreadsheet (.xlsx) where all the cells are formatted as "General" and the data can be a string of numbers "1234567" or a string of text then numbers "companyxyz_1234567."

If the first few rows in this column of the spreadsheet are a string of text then numbers (companyxyz_123456) everything works fine.

However, if the first few rows in this column of the spreadsheet are numeric only (1234567), then every entry in the column that contains text returns as NULL instead of the value once imported into the table.

I'm new to this system and have some basic knowledge in SQL and SQL coding but I'm at a loss here.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use a format file. Also save your xlsx as a csv to avoid these things

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  I'm getting some nasty error when trying to import a CSV that I'm trying to work through.  The original file is a CSV anyway so I'd rather do that so I can automate the process.

Answer (score -1):

There's no Error return's all records are successfully inserted.

Here's the simulation:

```
insert into table_3 (sampletext) values ('1234567')
```

Record has been inserted.

```
insert into table_3 (sampletext) values (1234567)
```

Also inserted with the following sampletext varchar(55)

My suggestion is:

Kindly `check` the data of your excel file by:

> Copy and paste the specific cell into notepad, maybe it had some
>   characters include on it.

Comment: When I paste it into notepad there are no special characters.  I tried your two examples as well and both were able to be inserted.  I also tried inserting strings of alpha and alpha-numeric and all of them can be inserted?